# How to efficiently send tons of get request with php

Tags: javascript, php, get, request, file-get-contents

I'm working on a project in which I have to develop a simple **PHP** based web module from where the user (admins) can **send SMS messages** (Followup) to students, as for the sake of advertisement and other needs.

The **SMS API** is very simple and I just need to send a **GET request** to a **Cross Origin Domain** along with the phone number and message.
I tested it with the `file_get_contents("sms_api_url?credentials");` and it works fine.

What worries me is that the SMS will be sent to **TONS of numbers** and so I have to send the request multiple times using a loop, which will take a lot of time and I think will be too much resource consuming. 
Also the max execution time for PHP is set to 30 seconds which  I don't want to change.

I thought to use the Client side **JavaScript** for sending cross origin request in a loop so that it wont affect my server but that wouldn't be secure as it would reveal the **API credentials**.

***What Technology should I use to accomplish my goals? and send tons of get request efficiently?***

Comment: store the messages in the database and use cron to send the messages backend.

Comment: Wh**a**t's **with** the rando**mly** bold wo**rds**, makes it hard to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send as many network requests as needed in less than 30 seconds are two requirements that kind of contradict themselves. Also, raw "efficiency" can just mean squeeze every single resource in the server, which not may be desirable.

Said that, I think the key points are:

- I may be wrong but, as far as I know, there're only two ways to prevent a non-authorised party from consuming a web service: private credentials and IP filtering. None are possible in browser-based JavaScript.
- Don't make a human being stare in front of the computer until a task of this kind completes. There's absolutely no need to and it can even cause the task to abort.
- If you need to send the same text to different recipients, find out whether the SMS provider has an API that allows to do it in a single API request. Large batch deliveries get one or two orders of magnitude harder when this feature is not available.

In short you need:

- A command line script
- A task scheduler (e.g. cron)
- Prefer server stability to maximum efficiency (you may even want to throttle your requests)

Answer (score 2):

You've told us nothing about the the actual volume you need to handle, the metrics for the processing/connection time nor what constraints there are on the implementation.

As it stands this is *way* too broad to answer. But some approaches you might consider are:

1) Running [concurrent requests](http://lampe2e.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/making-stuff-faster-with-curlmultiexec.html) - but note that just like domain sharding, this can undermine your bandwidth if over used

2) You can have PHP scripts running indefinitely *outside* the webserver (using the CLI SAPI) and these can be [launched from a web session](http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/php-and-long-running-processes.html).

> I thought to use the Client side JavaScript for sending cross origin request in a loop so that it wont affect my server but that wouldn't be secure as it would reveal the API credentials.

If you send directly to the endpoint, then yes, you'd need the credentials in the browser. But if you implement a proxy script which injects the credentials on your webserver then you can use your own credentials from the browser.

Using cron has certian advantages - but you really don't want to be spawning a task from crond to send one SMS message - it needs to run in batches, and you need to manage the concurrency.

You might want to consider switching to a different aggregator whom can offer bulk processing.

Regardless of the aproach you will need a way to store the messages/phone numbers and a locking mechanism around retrieval processing.

Personally, I'd be tempted to look at using an MTA for this or perhaps even Kannel - but that's more an approach for handling volumes in excess of 300,000 per day.

Answer (score 0):

Send the requests from the server, but don't do it in the PHP script that generates the page.

Instead, store information about the desired messages in a database.

Write another program which, periodically, checks the database for unsent messages and makes the call to the API. You could run it using cron.